# Question on completing the square obtaining the form $a(x+p)^2+q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, completing-the-square

From the last term in completing the square from the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$,
I was just wondering how $$-\left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+c = \left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)$$ 
I would have gotten $$-\left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+c=\left(c-\frac{b^2}{(2a)^2}\right)=\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)$$
Books final answer was the following when completing the square $$ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)$$

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: It's the last term in completing the square from the quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$

Comment: Um... I believe you're right. The denominator is supposed to be $4a^2$

Comment: The books final answer was $$a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)$$ @Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to multiply the $\left(\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2$ by $a$.

Comment: OOOOH! Yessss! Thanks! @Robert